# in the Cache API , what is the difference between using caches.match(event.request) and caches.match(event.request.url)

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, cacheapi

I'm working with services worker and I have the following code

```
  self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    const url = new URL(event.request.url)

    if (event.request.mode == "navigate") {
        const fetchData = fetch(event.request).catch(function () {
            //console.log("errr")
            return caches.match("/core/index.php/offline_controlador/index")
        });
        event.respondWith(fetchData)
        return;
    }

    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
 });
```

when i tried to get these files from the cache, it does not work, but when i change the code to

```
event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request.url).then(function(response) {
          return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
```

instead of

```
event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
              return response || fetch(event.request);
            })
        );
```

It works perfect

Comment: Hi Sergio, what is your url (is it localhost?), your server and which browser did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant section of the Cache Storage API specification is [5.4.2](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#dom-cache-matchall). (Although that applies to the `matchAll()` method of a `Cache` object, that's what ends up being called "under the hood" when you do `caches.match()`.

Of particular relevance to your question is step 2:

> If the optional argument request is not omitted, then:
>
> - If `request` is a `Request` object, then:
>
>   - Set `r` to `request`’s request.
>   - If `r`’s method is not `GET` and `options.ignoreMethod` is false, return a
>       promise resolved with an empty array.
> - Else if request is a string, then:
>
>   - Set `r` to the associated request of the result of invoking the initial
>       value of `Request` as constructor with `request` as its argument. If this
>       throws an exception, return a promise rejected with that exception.

To summarize, the biggest difference is that passing in a `Request` object as the first parameter can cause the `match()` to fail if the `Request` has a `method` of something other than `'GET'`. Maybe that's what you're bumping into.

Other than that, the two approaches should basically be the same, though passing in a `Request` is slightly more efficient, since the browser doesn't have to implicitly create a `Request` object based on the string.